# Search and highlight a pdf within webbrowser in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I'm using a WebBrowser-Controll in vb.net for showing pdf-files, simply by doing

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(output_filepath & "#view=Fit")
```

Acrobat Standard X and XI is used as well as IE11.

Now I'm trying to implement a search functionality for searching the pdf-files and, in case the search-term is found, focus on and highlight it. I did not realiy find a good hint. Is there a way? Which one?
Is more information needed?

I'm keen to read your hints...!

**EDIT:**
I want to search for words in a searchable pdf-file shown in the webbrowser-command.

Comment: you mean search for words in the pdf?

Comment: [This](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/13/highlight-words-in-webbrowser-control/) might help you.

Comment: @subaz: yes, I mean serch for words in a searchable pdf-file shown in the webbrowser-command.

Comment: @equisde: thank you, I'll have a look!